# AngularJS deal with multiple promises

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I´m currently working on an AngularJS controller which should work with multiple promises all returning a boolean value. Based on this boolean values a resulting boolean value will be determined. If all returned values are `true` also the result will be `true` but even if only one promise returns `false` also the result will be `false`. Currently all my service/DAO calls are chained up which causes some trouble if one promise is rejected. I guess there is a better way how to handle this situation.

**Controller Code:**

```
app.controller('PromiseController', ['$scope', 'FirstService', 'SecondService', 'ThirdService', 
    'FourthService', function ($scope, FirstService, SecondService, ThirdService, FourthService) {

    var vm = this;

    vm.statusResult = false;
    vm.statusSecond = null;
    vm.statusThird = null;
    vm.statusFourth = null;
    vm.statusFirst = null;

    SecondService.getStatus()       
    .then(function(returnData){
        vm.statusSecond = returnData;
    })
    .then(function(){
        return ThirdService.getStatus();
    })
    .then(function(returnData){
        vm.statusThird = returnData;
    })
    .then(function(){
        return FourthService.getStatus();
    })
    .then(function(returnData){
        vm.statusFourth = returnData;
    })
    .then(function(){
        return FirstService.getStatus();
    })
    .then(function(returnData){
        vm.statusFirst = returnData;
    })
    .then(function(){
        if(vm.statusThird&&vm.statusFourth&&vm.statusFirst&&vm.statusSecond){
            vm.statusResult = true;
        }

    });

    return this;

}]);
```

So I am searching for a better way how to deal with multiple promises and how to resolve the final result of all promises. Also the app shouldn't freeze while handling the results.

---

**EDIT**

The solution with `$q.all` from **@str** works fine for the final result but I also need the individual results of all services. How am I capable to also handle the single values while also handling the final result?

Comment: Can the services run in parallel?

Comment: `$q.all` or `Promise.all` could run all those promises in parallel then give you an array of their results.

Comment: i guess you can pass 2 callbacks to your then function which is success and error block. In both functions return the next promise object and save the state of rejected promise in a variable this way execution wont stop.

Comment: @str all the services are independent `$http` calls to the same server

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`$q.all`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q) to wait for all promises:

```
var promises = [
    FirstService.getStatus(),
    SecondService.getStatus(),
    ThirdService.getStatus(),
    FourthService.getStatus(),
];

$q.all(promises)
    .then(function (serviceResults) {
        vm.serviceResults = serviceResults; // result of first promise will be available in vm.serviceResults[0] 
        vm.statusResult = serviceResults.every(function (serviceResult) {
            return serviceResult;
        });
    })
    .catch(function() {
        vm.statusResult = false;
    });
```

Comment: This looks very good but I have a question: If the services return the following sequence `true`, `true`, `false`, `true` won't the last `true` override the `false`value due to the line `vm.statusResult = serviceResults.every(function (serviceResult) {
            return serviceResult;
        });`?

Comment: serviceResults.every will returns false if at least one serviceResult is false. So no it will not override. every means every values should return true.

Comment: @JohnDizzle No, as oliv37 wrote. `serviceResults` is an array holding all the results from the promises (e.g. `[true, true, false, true]`). And the `every` function only returns true when *every* value is true.

Comment: Thank you both for the clarification. I guess this solution will solve my current problem!

Comment: One last Question: Is there a way how to also get each individual result of the services? I also need the individual results as well as the final result

Comment: serviceResults is an array. So you want want the result of first promise, just call serviceResults[0], for the second one -> serviceResults[1] etc...

Comment: @JohnDizzle I extended the answer.